# Python tkinter : App not Responding if I click on gui

Tags: python, selenium, scheduler

So I made this app with selenium which will mark my Attendance daily and I'm using schedule to make it run every hour to mark my attendance
The problem is that ones the app starts the gui of my app will kind of freeze and if I click on it it will show not responding but it is working in background so I just want to keep the app running without it being showing "not responding"

how I have used the scheduler

```
import schedule

schedule.every(59).minutes.do(lambda :full_method(id_entry.get(), password_entry.get()))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

And maybe if there is some other scheduler that would not use while loop to run and will put the app to sleep and won't cause the "not responding" to occur idk

thanks anyway

Comment: on the spot, I'd say it is due to the while True loop. That thing is sucking up resources and freezing your scheduler.

Comment: And maybe if there is some other scheduler that would not use while loop to run and will put the app to sleep and won't cause the "not responding" to occur

Comment: Use Tkinter's `.after()` method to call `schedule.run_pending()` periodically.